# jQuery firing twice, event bubbling?

Tags: jquery

I have looked at all of the issues people are having with event bubbling and jQuery firing twice, but I can't figure out this issue.  I am only clicking in one DIV at a time, but the click handler is firing twice.

HTML

```
<div class="scroll-content-item" data-pid="1773">
    <img src="somefile" class="mixdock-img" data-pid="1773"/>
</div> 
<div class="scroll-content-item" data-pid="1777">
    <img src="someotherfile" class="mixdock-img" data-pid="1777"/>
</div>
```

jQuery...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var count = 0;

// On click, hide the currently displayed post and show the one clicked
$('.scroll-content-item').click(function () {
    count += 1;
    alert("count = "+count);
    event.stopPropagation();
});

});
```

What this does is show two alerts per click, each with the same count.  Count does increment on each click.

Comment: Maybe just a typo but in order to call `event.stopPropagation()` you have to add `event` as parameter to the function: `.click(function(event){...})`

Comment: I created a jsfiddle for this code.  Aside from adding in "test" text since I can't see the placeholder images, it works fine in FireFox:  http://jsfiddle.net/x7xQg/1/

Comment: What browser are you using? Are those div's in another div with `class="scroll-content-item"` on it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to pass the `event` variable into your function like so:

```
$('.scroll-content-item').click(function (event) {
```

Comment: +1 - overlooked this, though it wouldn't cause the issue at hand (in fact, erroring, it should prevent it heh).

Comment: Dude, that works!  How come it's not documented that way?  Or maybe I just overlooked it.  Thank you smart people of Stack Overflow.  this site is awesome.

Comment: @Ben - Well, if you look at the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/click/), you'll notice at the top they show the event object being passed to the handler. This is really the only mention of it in the docs there which (I agree) is odd. You're welcome and I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: OH and technically you're not passing the variable in, the variable is passed when the event is triggered. You're just giving it a name within your function to be able to access it. You could rename it to `e` or `evt` or whatever you want and it would still be the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

Comment: This didn't work for me unfortunately. My document.ready is being fired twice. I've been using $('.scroll-content-item').unbind('click'); by illvm's solution. Still pondering why it's firing twice though.

Comment: @c0d3Junk13 - How do you know it's being fired twice?

Comment: @RichardMarskell-Drackir I put an alert inside document.ready and it pops up twice

Comment: @c0d3Junk13 - Are you sure you're not attaching a function twice?

Comment: @RichardMarskell-Drackir In all honesty, I'm not 100% sure. The whole document html is fetched by DB calls. After the page loads, I searched for click on the DOM but didn't see anything suspicious. Just happy that the workaround is working.

Comment: @c0d3Junk13 - Well, it's good that you got it working, but you really should figure out what's causing the problem. Who knows what other unexpected behaviours could arise from it?! Try using the developer tools in your browser of choice and put a breakpoint on the alert call. Then, when execution is paused, check the call stack to see what's calling that function.

Comment: @RichardMarskell-Drackir Good call on that! Thank you sir! I'm still reading this weird code where the html is coming from the DB. So the more I read, the better I'll be able to debug too! Excellent idea, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I was not able to reproduce the issue on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ixabo4

Is it possible that you have included the jQuery script twice?

Comment: haha, I don´t know for the author of the question but you solved my problem!

Comment: This is turning out to be a very useful answer, I had the same issue and I did have the script included twice.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like overall your code is executing twice, two entire instances of your:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  //...
});
```

...are executing (each with their own `count` variable), ensure the script isn't being included twice in the page.  To confirm this is the issue, you can add an alert (which you should see twice at the moment):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  alert("init");
  //...
});
```

Comment: Great debug idea Nick.  I did that but it only alerted once.  So I guess it's something else.  Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Great idea, this solved it for me. I was included the source file twice :)

Comment: Thanks Nick, already mentioned but this is very clever debug trick and solved my issue!

Answer (score 3):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        var count = 0;

        // On click, hide the currently displayed post and show the one clicked
        $('.scroll-content-item').click(function(e, ui) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            count += 1;
            alert("count = " + count);
        });

    });
```

Works fine in my tests. Even with nested divs with the class "scroll-content-item". I would make sure you aren't attaching a listener to the click handler more than once.

If you can't find a place where the code is being called twice add the following before you attach the listener:

```
$('.scroll-content-item').unbind('click');
```

Comment: Yes, that works.  Not the best solution though.  I've been using it as a workaround.

Comment: I have the same problem however when i put a alert count under document.ready, it actually alerts twice. This is how I'm adding jquery: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='style.css'>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script> Though the .unbind workaround fixed the problem, I'm still curious why I was getting 2 document ready calls.

Comment: Also, if I remove one of the jquery inserts into website, it won't properly function as a mobile site.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.scroll-content-item').unbind('click').bind('click', function(e) {
    alert("clicked");
});
```